# Browser window opens maximized all the time. How to restore the last closed size of browser window

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I use

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

to launch a firefox page. And, selenium ChromeDriver Service for the chrome page.

However, the window opens maximized at all times. How do I make the window open in the same dimensions as it was while closing? i.e. in the size is restored properly.

Comment: did you used driver.manage().window().maximize();? if so comment it and try

Comment: I have commented it and tried. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom window size, although without more information I'm not sure if this will or won't fulfil your requirements:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
```